# Can I deploy (update) Single Python file to existing Google App Engine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

Is it possible to update single py file in existing GAE app.something like we update cron.yaml using, `appcfg.py update_cron`

Is there any way to update .py file?

Regrads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. If you change one file, you need to package and upload the whole application.

Comment: ...however, appcfg only uploads modified files, so it won't require uploading the whole app again.